# How do I test a class method - a method to convert a dictionary to a class object? PYTHON

Tags: python, class, methods, arguments

I am quite desperate in seeking to understand this question.

If you look at the attached screenshot, there is question 1a which is to define a class Student with the following specifications, and 1b which is to create a class method.

So far, I have trouble comprehending 1b because I can't seem to figure out how to test or even call the method?

How does this whole thing flow in your own understanding? [image]

My code so far:

```
class Student:

def __init__(self, student_dict: dict):
    self.name = student_dict["name"]
    self.results = student_dict["results"]

@classmethod #I dont understand this part
def dict_to_class_obj(cls, LIST: list[dict]):
    
    cls.theLIST = LIST

    return cls.dict_to_class_obj(LIST)      


def main():
print("Assignment 4")

student = {'name': 'Alfie', 'results': {
    'assignment_1': 10, 'assignment_2': 10, 'examination_1': 10}}


student_list = [{'name': 'Fus Ro Dah',
                'results': 
                        {'assignment_1': 10, 
                        'assignment_2': 10, 
                        'examination_1':10}
                }]

#Testing 1a
s1 = Student(student)
print(s1.name)
print(s1.results)

print("----------------")

#Testing 1b
s1.dict_to_class_obj(student_list) #??


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

I can't comprehend how to exactly do 1b, and test it. I understand that it needs a list parameter, but do I test it by creating an object of Student class with a list argument, then call that object method with the same argument??

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Forget about the classmethod. How would you conver that list, `student_list`, to a list of your `Student` objects? Note, each dict inside is the exact sort o dict your constructor accepts. You could just do somethine like `result = []` then `for d in student_list: result.append(Student(d))`, or `[Student(d) for d in student_list]`... does that help? Now how would you do that in the classmethod? Noting, the first argument,`cls` **is** `Student`.

Comment: you would just test it by doing `Student.dict_to_class_obj(student_list)`. You *could* use an instance, but that isn't very natural in this case.